# Unable to fully hide toolbar title when search view is open

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, searchview

[image]

I have created a custom toolbar. When I click search the search view is expanded but the toolbar title is not fully hide.

```
 if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
        }
    }

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_web_browser_action_bar, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customView);

        mActionBarTitleText = customView.findViewById(R.id.actionBarTitleText);
        mActionBarLogoImage = customView.findViewById(R.id.actionBarLogoImage);
        ImageView actionBarBackButton = customView.findViewById(R.id.actionBarBackButton);
        mActionBarLogoImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
    }
```

Please advice.

Thank you.